# I want to hide text which is in <span> . but why it's not working?

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to hide text which is in `<span>` . but why it's not working?

```
.pdf {text-indent: -9999}

<p>
   <a href="reader_overview.pdf" title="Open in a new Window" target="_blank"><img src="pdf.gif" alt="PDF" width="16" height="16" />
   <span class="pdf">PDF 34KB, Opens in a new window</span> </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> text-align
>
> Applies to:   block-level elements, table cells and inline blocks

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html

Span is, by default, inline.

The value it takes is also a *length* and so requires units if the value is non-zero.

There seems little point in including the information in the document if you are going to hide it though. I assume you are trying to provide information to screen reader users instead of all users … but that information is as useful to people not using screen readers.

Comment: "and inline blocks" doesn't cover this?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `display: inline` is not the same as `display: inline-block`. By default spans are inline and not in the least bit block like.

Comment: yes but not by default. it reads only if user allowed using change in scren reader settings

Comment: And visual mouse users only see them if they point at the link for a while, meanwhile people using a keyboard, breath switch or other non-pointing device with a normal visual display don't get to see the information at all.

Comment: As a rule of thumb — if you start trying to target information at different devices, you are doomed to failure.

Comment: you are right. but for sighted keyboard user they can get clue from icon. i want to do this for this type of design http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525076/what-is-preferred-accessible-and-semantically-correct-method-to-code-this-type-of

Comment: Why can't screen reader users get a clue from the icon? It has alt text.

Comment: "if you start trying to target information at different devices, you are doomed to failure" explain this"

Comment: @David - Alt text is "PDF" only because it's a CMS and i'm using one images for icon and only can add alt to that images

Comment: @David - Do you think then `title` is enough in this condition? is there any other better solution?

Comment: I'd get rid of the title attribute, get rid of the textual file type or set the alt attribute on the image to a blank string, leave the file size visible (its useful to *everyone*!), get rid of the target attribute, and set a content-disposition attachment header on the downloads so they trigger "Open or Save" instead of using an obnoxious browser plugin that could have people closing a window with their history in it by mistake.

Comment: you mean like this `<p>
   <a href="reader_overview.pdf"><img src="pdf.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
   34KB, Opens in a new window</a>
</p>` but then how screen reader user will know this is the PDF?

Comment: `<a href="reader_overview.pdf"><img src="pdf.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /> PDF</a> (34KB)`

Comment: but in this method PDF Icon and text "PDF" bot would be used. which is for for same thing

Comment: Then `<a href="reader_overview.pdf"><img src="pdf.gif" alt="PDF" width="16" height="16" /></a> (34KB)` (but there is something to be said for using icons as a visual cue for people who can skim and recognize them and text to describe what it actually means for those who cannot)

Answer (score 12):

Use `.pdf {display: none}`

Answer (score 7):

I thought hiding with CSS worked like this:

```
.pdf {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: but Display:none is skipped by screen reader i want to just hide this text from sighted user but it should be read by screen readers

Comment: You can have separate CSS for screen, print and screen reader media types. Check out the @media keyword: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: "screen reader media type" is really a different media for scree reader available?

Comment: Wrong. You can have separate stylesheets for "screen" and "aural" but **screen** readers are impacted by screen stylesheets.

Comment: @David: Sure? I would expect them to be affected by @speech or @aural (you know, because they are screen **readers**).

Comment: @Tomalack — Good ones respect aural stylesheets as well (at least for things like tone), but `display: none` for the screen still hides the content.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide it, use the CSS that is intended for that purpose:

```
.pdf { visibility: hidden; display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.pdf {display: block; height: 40px; line-height: 200px;}
```